# Failed prop type while doing prop validation in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm working on a React project, in which there is a context under the name of `CurrencyContext.js`. The whole project is running perfectly, however, I'm getting a console error that says `Failed prop type`.

**Full error message**

> Warning: Failed prop type: CurrencyContextProvider: prop type `children` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.This often happens because of typos such as `PropTypes.function` instead of `PropTypes.func`.

For more clarifications here is the code of `CurrencyContext.js`. Please let me know if something is not clear enough.

```
import React, {Component, createContext} from "react"

export const CurrencyContext = createContext()

class CurrencyContextProvider extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedCurrency: 'USD'
        }
    }

    setCurrency(c){
        this.setState({selectedCurrency: c})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CurrencyContext.Provider value={{...this.state, setCurrency: this.setCurrency.bind(this)}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </CurrencyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

CurrencyContextProvider.propTypes = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

export default CurrencyContextProvider;
```

Comment: Try to use `children: React.elementType`

Comment: @LucaPizzini That didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.ReactNode` is `undefined` in javascript. If you're using typescript it would be a type, but even that only exists at compile time and cannot be used for propTypes.

Instead, the way to do the children prop type is:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// ...
CurrencyContextProvider.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node
}
```